# In Lambda with Node.js and Axios, how do I pass a log entry as a variable to another axios function

Tags: node.js, function, aws-lambda, axios

I'm writing a Lambda function using Axios to make calls to my external API server. My goal is to perform two steps:

Step one is to authenticate my user to retrieve an access token.
Step two is to use that access token in order to GET server alarms.

The first part `axios.post` works and the access token shows in the logs. I cannot seem to set that as a variable to pass to the second step. If I have it as two separate functions it does not know what the token value is, so I was trying to potentially nest the axios functions to see if that could read the value. I now receive a `TypeError: (intermediate value)}.then is not a function`.

Here's where I stand with the the Lambda function. I appreciate the help!

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

    const apiUser = process.env.api_user;
    const apiPwd = process.env.api_pwd;

    var apiURL = "https://external-api-server.com:5454";

    var axios = require('axios');
    var userInfo = JSON.stringify({
        "user": {
            "admin_user": apiUser,
            "admin_pwd": apiPwd
        }
    });

    var head = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };

    return axios.post(apiURL + '/api/auth/', userInfo, head)
        .then(function(resp) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.data.access_token));
            var setToken = resp.data.access_token;

            return axios.get(apiURL + '/api/alarms?summary=&crit=&maj=&date=', {
                headers: {
                    'x-access-token': setToken,
                    'x-key': apiUser
                }
                .then(function(alarmResp) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(alarmResp.data));
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: it might be fine for a quick test, but if you ever move the code to be reusable you will need to fix a few things (e.g. not calling `callback`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was missing a parentheses after the `headers` and just before `.then(function(alarmResp)`. Here's the corrected formatting of the function:

```
...
      return axios.get(apiURL + '/api/alarms?summary=&crit=&maj=&date=', {
              headers: {
                  'x-access-token': setToken,
                  'x-key': apiUser
              }
          })   // <------ added parentheses here
          .then(function(alarmResp) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(alarmResp.data));
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
              console.log(err);
          });   // <------ moved semicolon here
    });
...
```